# Tensorflow save and load_model not working but save and load_weights does

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save, load

I am using tensorflow version 2.8.0:

I have seen this issue from multiple sources all over forums, githubs, and even some here for the past 5 years with no definitive answer that has worked for me... For some reason, in certain situations, a loaded model from a previous save yields very different results from the original model evaluation. I haven't seen any well documented and investigative questions about this so I thought I'd show my full code below (simple illustration of the issue).

This is an application of transfer learning from a pre-trained tensorflow model. The model is first trained through 5 epochs on train_data, then fine tuned (with more trainable params) for 5 more. Evaluating the model on test_data shows an accuracy of 0.5671. The model is then saved and loaded in .h5 format (I have also tried the tf SavedModel format and the result is the same). The resultant loaded_model yields an evaluation accuracy on the same, unaltered test_data of 0.4535.

The result should be the same (0.5671)... so to further investigate I decided to save the fine tuned model's weights independently, construct and compile the same model architecture in new_model, and load the saved model's weights into new_model. Evaluating new_model yields the correct result, an accuracy of 0.5671. ----- Okay, so it must be the weights not saving properly right? I pulled the weights from each of these three models (model, loaded_model, new_model) and compared their flattened results. They are all the same. I really have no idea what's going on here but I'm assuming it is not random initialization, because the loaded_model evaluation results really did not perform anywhere near the fine tuned model - I would assume they would converge much closer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(42)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import os
import pathlib
data_dir = pathlib.Path("101_food_classes_10_percent/train")
class_names = np.array(sorted([item.name for item in data_dir.glob('*')]))

train_dir = './101_food_classes_10_percent/train/'
test_dir = './101_food_classes_10_percent/test/'

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen=ImageDataGenerator()
train_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = train_dir,
                                         target_size = (224,224),
                                         batch_size = 32,
                                         class_mode='categorical')

test_data = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory = test_dir,
                                        target_size = (224,224),
                                        batch_size = 32,
                                        class_mode='categorical')

from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    preprocessing.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
    preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
    preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.2),
    preprocessing.RandomHeight(0.2),
    preprocessing.RandomWidth(0.2)
    #preprocessing.Rescaling(1/255.) in EfficientNet it's already scaled but could use this for non-scaled
], name = 'data_augmentation')
```

```
Found 7575 images belonging to 101 classes.
Found 25250 images belonging to 101 classes.
```

```
# Build headless model - Feature Extraction

# Setup base with frozen layers
base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False)
base_model.trainable=False

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (224,224,3))

x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x) # Pool base_model's outputs into a feature vector

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation='softmax')(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs,outputs)
model.compile('Adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
data_augmentation (Sequentia (None, None, None, 3)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
efficientnetb0 (Functional)  (None, None, None, 1280)  4049571   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 101)               129381    
=================================================================
Total params: 4,178,952
Trainable params: 129,381
Non-trainable params: 4,049,571
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
history = model.fit(train_data, validation_data=test_data,
          validation_steps=int(0.15*len(test_data)),
          epochs=5, callbacks = [checkpoint_callback])
```

```
Epoch 1/5
237/237 [==============================] - 63s 230ms/step - loss: 3.4712 - accuracy: 0.2482 - val_loss: 2.4446 - val_accuracy: 0.4497
Epoch 2/5
237/237 [==============================] - 52s 221ms/step - loss: 2.3575 - accuracy: 0.4561 - val_loss: 2.0051 - val_accuracy: 0.5093
Epoch 3/5
237/237 [==============================] - 51s 216ms/step - loss: 1.9838 - accuracy: 0.5265 - val_loss: 1.8313 - val_accuracy: 0.5360
Epoch 4/5
237/237 [==============================] - 51s 212ms/step - loss: 1.7497 - accuracy: 0.5761 - val_loss: 1.7417 - val_accuracy: 0.5461
Epoch 5/5
237/237 [==============================] - 53s 221ms/step - loss: 1.6035 - accuracy: 0.6141 - val_loss: 1.7012 - val_accuracy: 0.5601
```

```
model.evaluate(test_data)
```

```
790/790 [==============================] - 87s 110ms/step - loss: 1.7294 - accuracy: 0.5481
[1.7294203042984009, 0.5480791926383972]
```

```
# Fine tuning: unfreeze some layers, lower leaning rate by 10x
base_model.trainable=True

# Refreeze every layer except last 5, adjust tiner tuned features down the model

for layer in base_model.layers[:-5]:
    layer.trainable=False

# recompile and lower learning rate by 10x

model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 

model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
data_augmentation (Sequentia (None, None, None, 3)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
efficientnetb0 (Functional)  (None, None, None, 1280)  4049571   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 101)               129381    
=================================================================
Total params: 4,178,952
Trainable params: 910,821
Non-trainable params: 3,268,131
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
# Fine Tune for 5 more epochs starting with last epoch left off at:

fine_tune_epochs=10 # Total number of epochs we're after: 5 feature extraction, 5 fine tuning

history_fine_tune = model.fit(train_data,
                              validation_data = test_data,
                              validation_steps=int(0.15*len(test_data)),
                              epochs = fine_tune_epochs,
                              initial_epoch = history.epoch[-1])
```

```
Epoch 5/10
237/237 [==============================] - 59s 220ms/step - loss: 1.3571 - accuracy: 0.6543 - val_loss: 1.6403 - val_accuracy: 0.5567
Epoch 6/10
237/237 [==============================] - 51s 213ms/step - loss: 1.2478 - accuracy: 0.6688 - val_loss: 1.6805 - val_accuracy: 0.5596
Epoch 7/10
237/237 [==============================] - 46s 193ms/step - loss: 1.1424 - accuracy: 0.6964 - val_loss: 1.6352 - val_accuracy: 0.5736
Epoch 8/10
237/237 [==============================] - 45s 191ms/step - loss: 1.0902 - accuracy: 0.7065 - val_loss: 1.6494 - val_accuracy: 0.5657
Epoch 9/10
237/237 [==============================] - 46s 193ms/step - loss: 1.0229 - accuracy: 0.7275 - val_loss: 1.6348 - val_accuracy: 0.5633
Epoch 10/10
237/237 [==============================] - 45s 191ms/step - loss: 0.9704 - accuracy: 0.7434 - val_loss: 1.6990 - val_accuracy: 0.5670
```

```
model.evaluate(test_data)
```

```
790/790 [==============================] - 83s 105ms/step - loss: 1.6578 - accuracy: 0.5671
[1.657836675643921, 0.5670890808105469]
```

```
model.save("./101_food_classes_10_percent/big_modelh5")
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./101_food_classes_10_percent/big_modelh5.h5")
loaded_model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
data_augmentation (Sequentia (None, None, None, 3)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
efficientnetb0 (Functional)  (None, None, None, 1280)  4049571   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 101)               129381    
=================================================================
Total params: 4,178,952
Trainable params: 910,821
Non-trainable params: 3,268,131
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
loaded_model.evaluate(test_data)
```

```
790/790 [==============================] - 85s 104ms/step - loss: 2.1780 - accuracy: 0.4535 - loss: 2.1790 - accuracy
[2.1780412197113037, 0.4534653425216675]
```

```
# Try save_weights to another model
model.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (224,224,3))

x = data_augmentation(inputs)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x) # Pool base_model's outputs into a feature vector

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation='softmax')(x)

new_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs,outputs)
new_model.compile('Adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
new_model.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
data_augmentation (Sequentia (None, None, None, 3)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
efficientnetb0 (Functional)  (None, None, None, 1280)  4049571   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_2 ( (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 101)               129381    
=================================================================
Total params: 4,178,952
Trainable params: 910,821
Non-trainable params: 3,268,131
_________________________________________________________________
```

```
new_model.load_weights('my_model_weights.h5')
# Saving weights works... but not save and load_model
new_model.evaluate(test_data)
```

```
790/790 [==============================] - 88s 109ms/step - loss: 1.6578 - accuracy: 0.5671
[1.6578353643417358, 0.5670890808105469]
```

```
# Check if weights are the same?
m1 = model.get_weights()
m2 = new_model.get_weights()
m3 = loaded_model.get_weights()

len(m1)==len(m2)==len(m3)
```

```
True
```

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el

m1 = flatten(m1)
m2 = flatten(m2)
m3 = flatten(m3)

print(list(m1)==list(m2))
print(list(m1)==list(m3))
```

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not saved your entire model using `.h5` extension, but you are using `.h5` for `saving the weights`. 
Please check below code section:

```
model.save("./101_food_classes_10_percent/big_modelh5")  # add .h5
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./101_food_classes_10_percent/big_modelh5.h5")
loaded_model.summary()
```

Use this code to save the entire model to a `HDF5` file format and try again loading it:

```
model.save("./101_food_classes_10_percent/big_modelh5.h5")
```

Check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model) for more details on saving model in `.hdf5` format.